# Swift/Xcode - No response from button in custom annotation view

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, mkmapview, selector

I have created a custom annotation view, as described here: https://sweettutos.com/2016/03/16/how-to-completely-customise-your-map-annotations-callout-views/

It works fine and displays the correct data/info.
The problem seems to be that there is no respons to .touchUpInside from the added button.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.deleteFromAnnot(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)

button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 16, y: 543, width: 268, height: 30)
button.backgroundColor = .yellow
calloutView.addSubview(button)


@objc func deleteFromAnnot(sender: UIButton)
{
    print("Do something")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have set your button target incorrectly.

**Replace**

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.deleteFromAnnot(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
```

**With**

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteFromAnnot(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
```